# Integer not comparing equal to its value

Tags: c++, int, comparison-operators

I've got a piece of code I am trying to debug, which is producing bizarre results. An integer, which very clearly contains the value six, compares false to the literal 6.
In my code, this code:

```
int allGreen = 0;
int index = 0;
while (ch->fb[index]->selection_color() == FL_GREEN) 
{
    ++allGreen;
    ++index;
}
std::cout << allGreen << std::endl;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << (allGreen == 6) << std::endl;
```

Produces the output:

```
6
false
```

I am compiling with g++ 4.8.2 on Ubuntu.

How can this possibly happen?

Edit: Removing all green from the condition doesn't help.
Edit 2: index and allGreen are equal, as expected. Neither is equal to 6, despite both being 6.

Comment: Can we have "some condition" so we can run this code ourselves

Comment: Sorry, some condition is not very helpful since it is tightly integrated with the rest of the code base.

Comment: Some condition is "ch->fb[allGreen]->selection_color() == FL_GREEN"

Comment: Is everything except "some condition" the actual code?

Comment: If I replace (some condition) with (allGreen < 6), I can compile and run the program (under MacOS/X 10.9.5, clang 600.0.57) and get the results:  6   true

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Specifically are you sure `allGreen` is an `int`?

Comment: The code is copy/pasted here and "some condition" is the only change. 
If I change the condition to allGreen < 6, it works for me, too.

Comment: I'll add the condition to the question, since it seems to somehow be causing this.

Comment: @Patrick The example should be minimum, **complete**, and **verifiable**.

Comment: I can't create a minimum, complete, and verifiable example. I realize it is recommended that you do so, but I can't seem to create one that triggers this problem.

Comment: Is this code multithreaded at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the size of `ch->fb` array? If it is 6 or less, it could be compiler optimizing undefined behavior here.

When seeing some simple loop like

```
while ( a[i] ) i++;
```

Compiler can make an assumption that `i` never goes outside of `a` array, otherwise program invokes undefined behavior. That is `i` lies between `0` and `size of a - 1`.

Later, if compiler sees something like `i == 8`, there `8` is larger than `size of a - 1`, it replaces this condition with `false`.

Just to be sure, you can look at assembly code.

Comment: The size of ch->fb is 6.

Comment: Then I will expand my answer to show what happening

Comment: It looks like you are correct about the problem. Changing the size to 7 fixes the problem. I had noticed that it was running over the end of the array (I didn't write the code), but didn't think it mattered since I was getting the number 6 back. I would be very interested to learn why this breaks the comparison.

Comment: That is very interesting. It does make sense.

Comment: @Patrick As a wise old Chinese Monk once said, "Undefined behavoir is undefined". Seriously, look at [this excellent llvm blog post](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) about why anything can happen once UB comes into it and how the compiler doesn't even know UB is happenning most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

The literal '6' is not an integer and does not have a value of 6.

Comment: I didn't use single quotes in the code. I guess my wording was pretty poor.

Answer (score 1):

As deniss already pointed out, accessing an array out of bounds is undefined behaviour, so maybe that's the cause. Make sure to check for the array's bounds, too.

So if it's OK to count every selection_color of the array, you could try:

```
const int MAX_FB_VALUES = 6;

// ...

int countOfGreen = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FB_VALUES; ++i)
{
    if(ch->fb[i]->selection_color() == FL_GREEN)
        ++countOfGreen;
}

std::cout << countOfGreen << std::endl;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << (countOfGreen == MAX_FB_VALUES) << std::endl;
```

Although it would be better to use a container anyway, of course.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that running out of bounds could break the future comparison, so I didn't worry about that part of the code. I would certainly have used a container, but this code was given to me in this state. It would be quite interesting to learn how that breaks the comparison between 6 and 6.